# JavaFX mouseEvent method getSceneX() stops after holding mouse buttons

Tags: javafx

```
public void setListeners() {
    for(Scene s : Org.scenes) {
        s.setOnMouseMoved(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                mouseX = event.getSceneX();
                mouseY= event.getSceneY();

            }

        });
    }
}
```

this code works well, however whenever mouse1 or mouse2 is held down, the code does not work, and the mouseX and mouseY variables stay at the same value, despite the mouse being moved around. I cannot understand why holding the mouse buttons pause the updating of the variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you press any button on the mouse that's no more considered as mouse move event, instead it becomes a mouse click event and if you hold the mouse button and move the cursor it will be a mouse drag event. So try adding new listeners `setOnMouseClicked()` or `setOnMouseDragged()`

```
    s.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

                @Override
                public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                    //what you want to do

                }

            });

    s.setOnMouseDragged(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

                @Override
                public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                    //what you want to do

                }

            });
```

Comment: Thank you, using setOnMouseDragged with the same method body helped to fix the issue